# Electrons Getting mass from energy

Tags: energy, electrons, mass-energy

According to relation $E=mc^2$ energy and mass are equivalent. So, when an electron in its orbit gets energy from out, does its mass increase? If not, where is the energy stored?

I am not understanding how electrons store energy in them . Does it change the mass of electrons or they immediately release the energy

Comment: But the questions is worth asking, consider an excited atom, for which you can calculate a mass difference when it gets into ground state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called the mass deficit. A free electron has a certain mass, and a free proton also has a certain mass. The mass of a hydrogen atom is less than the sum of those masses. The difference in the mass between the hydrogen atom and the sum of the free proton and electron masses is called the mass deficit, and it is equal to the ionization energy ($/c^2$)

The concept of mass deficit applies in general to all bound systems. The binding energy is a reflection of the mass deficit.

The mass deficit does not belong to either the proton or the electron individually, but to the hydrogen atom as a whole, so the question of where the electron stores that energy does not arise because it is not stored in the electron but in the atom as a whole. For a system to store energy internally requires some internal degree of freedom, and an electron has no internal degrees of freedom. A hydrogen atom does, specifically the degree to which the atom is excited which indicates how close the electron is to the proton in terms of atomic orbitals. Each orbital corresponds to an amount of energy that can be contained by the degree of freedom in the atom. If a particle has no internal degrees of freedom then energy can only be stored in KE.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 from me.

Comment: *"The concept of mass deficit applies in general to all bound systems."* Well, for the binding of baryons the binding energy is positive, but the notion that binding energy is reflected in the mass of the system still applies.

Comment: Can we find out the mass of the electron has when its bounded to the nucleus?

Comment: @KarthikV What most physicists mean by “mass” is a Lorentz-invariant quantity that does not change. The mass of an electron is 9.1e-31 kg, regardless of its state of motion or any force acting on it. If you learned about any other kind of mass, you  should unlearn it.

Comment: @KarthikV You can compute the mass of a bound hydrogen atom at rest by computing its energy and dividing by $c^2$. To a good approximation, the atom’s energy is the sum of five parts. In decreasing order by magnitude, they are the rest energy of the proton, the rest energy of the electron, the (negative) electrostatic potential energy beyween them, the kinetic energy of the electron, and the kinetic energy of the proton. The negative electrostatic energy explains why the mass of a hydrogen atom is *less than* the mass of its constituents.

Comment: I am not understanding how electrons store energy in them . Does it change the mass of electrons or they immediately release  the energy

Comment: @TheBroly Where does a moving particle “store” its kinetic energy? The question doesn’t make sense. Energy is just a number we assign to a system, which happens to coincide to the gravitational mass (the weight measured on a scale), and doesn’t have to be “stored” anywhere.

Comment: @bob knighton So it means it just increases the speed of electron immediately ?

Comment: @TheBroly No, that was just an example to show that energy doesn’t have to be “stored” anywhere. A hydrogen atom is a bound state of an electron and a proton, and it doesn’t make sense to talk about them individually in terms of their energy, as it is the *interaction* between them which causes the observed energy change. I think a lot of the confusion here is that you’re thinking of an electron as a classical object with “speed” and “position,” which is a viewpoint that becomes flawed at the scale of atomic physics.

Comment: @TheBroly I have added some more detail about the energy storage in an electron

Answer (score 1):

Rest mass of an electron is always the same, it cannot be changed by interaction with outside bodies (at least in standard theories).

When atomic electrons get excited and acquire energy $\Delta E$ from outside, this energy may go to EM energy of the system or to kinetic energy of its material parts, or to some other kind of energy.

According to relativity and EM theory, provided the energy stays near the system(so it isn't radiated or lost from the system in other way), no matter the details of where the energy is in the system, it will always manifest as increased inertial mass $\Delta E/c^2$ of the whole system.